# Python soft tf-idf function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I am looking for a soft tf/idf library. Currently, I am using tfidf function from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) for my program. The `TfIdfVectorizer`function in this library does strict matching as also mentioned in their docs i.e `analyzer == 'word'`. Here I want to include distance matching function like edit distance or jaro to do soft matching wherein

```
if distance >= 0.8:
 analyzer == word
```

I was looking for existing libraries in python for this. I found this [library](http://anhaidgroup.github.io/py_stringmatching/v0.2.x/Tutorial.html) but unable to install it respective of meeting all the requirements. Are their more libraries that can be directly used in.

I tried to change the function by myself but I am not sure after I do distance match, how can I pass the data in again to the `fit_transform`?

```
def string_match(tokens):
    for i in range(0, len(tokens)):
        s1 = tokens[i]
        s2 = tokens[i+1]
        jw = distance.get_jaro_distance(s1, s2, winkler=True, scaling=0.1)
        if jw >= 0.80:
            return ??
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), tokenizer=dummy, preprocessor=dummy, use_idf=True,  analyzer=string_match)
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(data["tokens"])
```

Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if jw >= 0.8? Are you keeping both s1 and s2?

Comment: if jw >= 0.8 then it should keep both s1 and s2 and treat it 2 different strings.

Comment: I think your not really after a soft tfidf but after a filtering operation on your tokens using the jaro_distance, followed by a tfidf. Would you agree? If this is correct, then it should be straightforward to implement.

Comment: yes, this is how I want it to be.. Not too hard with the initial token matching.